# Convert IIS htaccess to Apache htaccess split URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis

first post - did a good search and couldn't find what I am after.

I have a PHP website on IIS server using htaccess rewrite rules and need to move to linux/Apache

My URL's 
First link https://www.radiatorwholesalers.com.au/ford_radiators/

Then https://www.radiatorwholesalers.com.au/ford_radiators/falcon/

and finally https://www.radiatorwholesalers.com.au/falcon/ba-4.0l%2002-05%20man/252.htm

These rules work in IIS

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.htm$ proddetail.php?prod=$3 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ catalogue.php?mfname=$1&modelname=$2
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ catalogue.php?mfname=$1
```

I have edited this to the following to get it to start working - but I am not picking up the modelname (falcon)

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.htm$ proddetail.php?prod=$3
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /catalogue.php?mfname=$1&modelname=$2
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /catalogue.php?mfname=$1
```

Second line I had to add extra (.*)/ to pickup mfname - not sure why?
Had to add / to pickup correct path.
Neither were required under IIS.

Seems the second rule is replaced by the third.

My htaccess as it stands

```
    Options +Indexes
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.htm$ proddetail.php?prod=$3
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ catalogue.php?mfname=$1&modelname=$2
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ catalogue.php?mfname=$1
```

Comment: IIS does not support htaccess natively, so you must forget to post some details on "These rules work in IIS".

Comment: On my server I believe I have Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite 3 installed which allows htaccess to work - I think